# SQL Server update all columns from another table rows

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rows

I have two tables, one is `sensor_pool` which is changes `temp_cel` value with timer interval

**sensor_pool**

```
| address | temp_cels |
|---------------------|
| sensor1 | 83C       |
| sensor2 | 82C       |
| sensor3 | 85C       |
| sensor4 | 85C       |
| sensor5 | 84C       |
```

and another table `sensor_history` which I have columns created dynamically (added columns with sensor address as column name). I was able to capture the datetime but not the `temp_cels` from the other table.

```
INSERT INTO sensor_history(datetime) VALUES(" & dtfStr & ")
```

- `dtfStr = timestamp`

**sensor history**

```
|    datetime    | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | sensor4 | sensor5 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 12022013080513 |  NULL   |  NULL   |  NULL   |  NULL   |  NULL   |
```

So far I have this query which is inside a for loop (for getting the columns)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT datetime FROM sensor_history where datetime='" & dtfStr & "') 
MERGE sensor_history sh USING sensor_pool sp ON [(SELECT '" & dgvSensors.Rows(l).Cells(0).Value & "' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='sensor_history' AND COLUMN_NAME='" & dgvSensors.Rows(l).Cells(0).Value & "')] = sp.sens_code 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET sh.[" & dgvSensors.Rows(l).Cells(0).Value & "] = st.temp_cels 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([" & dgvSensors.Rows(l).Cells(0).Value & "]) VALUES (st.temp_cels);"
```

the dgvSensors datagridview is same as the sensor_pool table. vb.net + SQL Server

This is what my target result should be:

```
|    datetime    | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | sensor4 | sensor5 | 
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 12022013080513 |   83C   |   82C   |   85C   |   85C   |   84C   |
```

hope someone could help me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO sensor_history(datetime,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,sensor4,sensor5) 
VALUES(getdate(),
select temp_cels from sensor_pool where address='sensor1',
select temp_cels from sensor_pool where address='sensor2',
select temp_cels from sensor_pool where address='sensor3',
select temp_cels from sensor_pool where address='sensor4',
select temp_cels from sensor_pool where address='sensor5')
```